# Method with restrict parameter

Tags: java, android

When you try to give another value to the 3rd argument in `Toast.makeText` other than `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` or `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` it won't accept.

I need to create a method and use the same type of restriction: it can only be accepted three values which I'll define previously using constants.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Create ENUM with as many values as you want and then in the method place the parameter as ENUM.VALUE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict the user by creating your own enum. Sample code:

```
public enum Notification {
    LONG,
    SHORT
}
```

Method which I want to restrict:

```
private void methodName(String value1, Notification value2){
// Write whatever you want to perform
}
```

Now, this method can only be called like:

```
methodName("", Notification.LONG); // Second Parameter is allowed only from your custom enum
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks @Yasir

Comment: You can achieve the same functionality by using interface. Toast uses custom interface. Implementation of interfaces is same as just I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Throw `IllegalArgumentException` from your method if argument passed is not something you want.